# How can we do functional testing with JMeter and integrate with Maven

Tags: html, rest, maven, jmeter, report

I am trying to do API end points testing with JMeter. I am able to create test cases using JMeter GUI. But, facing while integrating JMeter with Maven Project. Please Help me.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us a bit more about what problems you are facing.

Comment: Currently , am able to get load test reports with jmeter-maven-plugin plugin.But, in that report didn't see failed requests those things. How can i enable ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to display the details of the failed requests, [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) is capable of only generating a [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which failures reporting capabilities are limited to:

1. The error table providing a summary of all errors and their proportion in the total requests

   [image]
2. The Top 5 Errors by Sampler table providing for every Sampler (excluding Transaction Controller by default) the top 5 Errors :

   [image]

---

So the options are in:

1. Modify the response message and add to it the information you need using i.e. [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener)
2. Use [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) Listener to store request and response data and whatever else you need into a separate file
3. Amend the [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) templates in the [report-template](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.2.1/bin/report-template) folder according to your needs and configure JMeter to use this modified template folder for the dashboard generation
4. Any combination of all above

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ Dmitri T. Can we get report end point wise whether it was passed or failed rather than based on error like 403 -2 end points, 404 -4 kind of thing